# Spectral theorem for commuting operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory

Let $A_{1},...,A_{n}$ be densely defined self-adjoint operators on a separable Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Suppose these have a common dense domain $D\subset \mathscr{H}$ and satisfy commutation relations:
$$A_{i}A_{j}-A_{j}A_{i} = 0 \quad \forall i,j = 1,...,n$$
By the spectral theorem, there exists a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$, a unitary operator $U: \mathscr{H} \to L^{2}(\Omega,\mu)$ and complex-valued functions $g_{1},...,g_{n}$ on $\Omega$ such that $A_{i}$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication by $g_{i}$.

On [Mathematical Aspects of Quantum Field Theory](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=u9M9PFLNpMMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), the authors state the following, without proof (I am adapting the notations here). Suppose the set of operators $A_{1},...,A_{n}$ form a complete system, in the sense that any other operator $B$ which commutes with all $A_{1},...,A_{n}$ is of the form $B = f(A_{1},...,A_{n})$, for some Borel measurable function $f$. Then, the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is unique and can be taken to be $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Borel measure.

I don't see how to prove this result, and also I haven't found this result anywhere I looked. Any help or reference is appreciated.

Comment: Your formulation of the spectral theorem for commuting self-adjoint operators is not correct. What you need is that the operators commute strongly, which is stronger than commutation on a common dense subspace (or even common core for the operators). And it should be commutation, not anti-commutation anyway.

Comment: @MaoWao thanks for the comment. I fixed the wrong sign in the commutation relation. You actually solved one of my questions: it is not clear by the authors presentation what they mean by commutation relations, since they only mention the term. You mean commutation relation in the strong sense = commutation of all its projection valued measures?

Comment: Yes, commutation of the projection valued-measures or equivalently all bounded Borel functions of the operators. These kind of issues are carefully discussed in Schmüdgen's book on *Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert spaces*.